# Completions of ramified maps of families of curves along sections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $p : X\rightarrow Y$ be a finite morphism of smooth projective curves over $A := \mathbb{Z}[1/M]$.

Let $C =  \text{Spec }A\stackrel{i_C}{\longrightarrow} X(A)$, and $D = \text{Spec A}\stackrel{i_D}{\longrightarrow} Y(A)$ be sections, and suppose $p(C) = D$. Further, suppose $p : X\rightarrow Y$ is etale away from $D$, and is tamely ramified above $D$. Suppose the ramification index of $p$ at $C$ is $e$.

1. Can we write the completion of $Y$ along $D$ as $\text{Spec }A[[t]]$ for some uniformizer $t$ along $D$? (I think this is true at least if $i_D^*\Omega^1_{Y/A}$ is trivial (ie, free), though I'm unsure if this condition is necessary).
2. Suppose (1) holds (either without additional assumptions, or by making $M$ bigger if necessary), then can we necessarily write the completion of $X$ along $C$ as $\text{Spec }A[[s]]$ for some uniformizer $s$ along $C$ satisfying $us^e = t$, where $u\in A^\times$?

In the above can we take $t,s$ to be *algebraic* uniformizers? (ie, uniformizers coming from local sections of the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ or $\mathcal{O}_Y$)

References would also be appreciated.